# Move a section above a tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I started learning LaTex and today i have started with tikz.. but i have run into a problem and i hope it's not absolutely stupid. I have (almost) finished my figure and now i wanted to create a section. I have put the section above my tikz enviroment but even then, it shows below the figure in the pdf… how do i fix this?
[image: pdf output]

my code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
%opening
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}

  \section*{\LARGE Deriving; $y(t)=\hat{y}\cdot\sin(\omega t)$} %How do i get this up
hello

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{circlecol}{HTML}{004AAD}
    \definecolor{xaxis}{HTML}{8C52FF}
    \definecolor{anglecon}{HTML}{6C0EAD}
    \definecolor{yaxis}{HTML}{FF66C4}
    \definecolor{hypo}{HTML}{38B6FF}

\draw [lightgray, dashed](0,-2) -- (0,2);
\draw [lightgray, dashed](-2,0) -- (2,0);
\draw [<->](2,0) -- (7.5,0) node [below] {$t$};
\draw [<->](2.25,-2) -- (2.25,2) node [left]{$y$};
\fill [hypo](0,0) -- (0.4,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=40, radius=0.4] -- cycle;
    \draw[line width=0.35mm, yaxis] (1.532,0) -- (1.532, 1.286)node[left, midway] {$y$}; 
    \draw[line width=0.35mm, hypo] (0,0) -- (1.532, 1.286) node [left, midway] {$\hat{y}$};
    \draw [line width=0.35mm, xaxis](0,0) -- (1.547,0) node [below, midway] {$\Delta t$};
\draw [line width=0.25mm, circlecol](0,0) circle [radius=2];
\fill [circlecol] (0,0) circle [radius=0.03];
\draw[->, yaxis, dashed] (1.532, 1.286) -- (7.5, 1.286);
\draw[circlecol] (2.25,0) sin (3,2) cos (3.75,0) sin (4.5,-2) cos (5.25, 0) sin(6,2) cos(6.75, 0) sin(7.5,-2);
\foreach \x in {3,3.75,...,6.75}\draw (\x,0.05) -- (\x,-0.05);
\foreach \y in {-1.5, -1,...,1.5}\draw (2.2,\y) -- (2.3,\y);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Harmonic Oscillator}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please extend your code into an example that can be compiled please, as it stands it cannot be compiled by people trying to help you

Comment: yes, sorry. i fixed it

Comment: No worries, just helps people help, +1 for including code, hope someone can help! `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chaging this line of Your code:

```
\begin{figure}
```

in

```
\begin{figure}[h]
```

Your output become:

[image]

Comment: For placement option is better to use `[htb]` . By this you gives to LaTeX  more freedom for placement of figures (or tables) floats positions on pages.

Comment: Oh my god it was that simple  thank you!!

Comment: You are wellkome.